# PHP ¿Cómo ordenar estas tablas?

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, datatables

Estoy haciendo un proyecto donde uso por primera vez php y quizás esta pregunta es bastante básica pero no pude encontrar la respuesta.

La pregunta surge con esta pantalla donde el usuario puede visualizar varias tablas pero estas se ven desacomodadas. Quiero que se vean ordenadas y parejas.

**Codigo php:**

```
    <?php
    $db_host = 'localhost'; 
    $db_user = 'root';
    $db_pass = ''; 
    $db_name = 'Proyecto';

    $conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
    if (!$conn) {
        die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());  
    }

     $sql = 'SELECT * FROM tecnica1';
    $sql1 = 'SELECT * FROM empadronamiento';
    $sql2 = 'SELECT * FROM inspeccion';
    $sql3 = 'SELECT * FROM SistemaInfGeografica';   
    $sql4 = 'SELECT * FROM tecnica2';

    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $query1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
    $query2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
    $query3 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql3);
    $query4 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql4);

    if (!$query) {
        die ('SQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
    }

                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
                        {
                            echo    '<tr>
                        <td class="tg-r8b1" style="text-align:center;">'.$row['Mes'].'</td>
                        <td  style="text-align:center;">'.$row['M'].'</td>
                        <td  style="text-align:center;">'.$row['MH'].'</td>
                        <td  style="text-align:center;">'.$row['DJ'].'</td>
                        <td  style="text-align:center;">'.$row['R'].'</td>
                        <td  style="text-align:center;">'.$row['PO'].'</td>
                        <td  style="text-align:center;">'.$row['POTNM'].'</td>
                        ';}

                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query1))
                        {
                            echo   
                        '
                        <td  style="text-align:center;">'.$row['CargaTotal'].'</td>
                        <td  style="text-align:center;">'.$row['DescargaTotal'].'</td>
                        <td  style="text-align:center;">'.$row['DescargaDSIG'].'</td>
                        ';}

                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query2))
                        {
                            echo
                        '
                        <td  style="text-align:center;">'.$row['CargaTotal'].'</td>
                        <td  style="text-align:center;">'.$row['DescargaTotal'].'</td>
                        <td  style="text-align:center;">'.$row['DescargaDSIG'].'</td>
                        ';}

                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query3))
                        {
                            echo
                        '
                        <td  style="text-align:center;">'.$row['FCGrabadas'].'</td>
                        <td  style="text-align:center;">'.$row['FCGrabVuelos'].'</td>
                        ';}

                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query4))
                        {
                            echo
                        '
                        <td  style="text-align:center;">'.$row['FCConformadas'].'</td>

                        </tr>';}
?>
```

Se que el código no es el mejor pero todavía estoy aprendiendo a mostrar varias tablas (de mysql) a la vez y esta fue una forma que me salió.

[image: Tablas en pantalla]

Como podrán notar en la barra de navegacion inferior, todos los datos estan "acostados" uno al lado del otro.
Sospecho que tiene algo que ver con la columna con los meses. Esa columna está hecha con HTML y tal vez eso hace que no se pueda concatenar.

Comment: Haz una única query con todos los datos que recorras con un único while para crear la tabla con integridad. Cada vez que recorres un while añades celdas a continuación del final del anterior.

Comment: lo mismo que dice @Carmen el while solo debe ser uno, por que de lo contrario por cada while que declaras es como si quisieras construir una tabgla nueva

Comment: Creo que tu error está en html mas que en php, fijate que abres un "<tr>" y no lo cierras hasta el final.

Comment: Recuerda que el tr abre la linea y los td son las columnas. Esto lo vas a ver mejor en https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp y recuerda que siempre puedes ver el código de la página presionando F12 en el navegador, esto suele ser de mucha ayuda. Éxitos!

Comment: Tomé el consejo de @Carmen e hice una única query relacionando tablas para que se vea todo en un while. Ahora las tablas se ven ordenadas! Gracias a todos!

Comment: Estupendo @Naza, si te parece responde a la pregunta con la solución y acéptala para que no quede como pendiente de responder.

Comment: @Naza es importante que la respuesta este como respuesta, y no en la pregunta. Saca la respuesta de ahi, ponela como respuesta, y despues aceptala. Explica porque lo que hiciste soluciono el problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias a los que comentaron mi duda!

Logré que se vea bien, tuve que unir los queries para que se vea todo en una misma tabla y no separado en whiles ya que eso hacia que se creen distintas tablas.

Acá el nuevo codigo:

```
$sql = 'SELECT M.Mes, T1.M, T1.MH, T1.DJ, T1.R, T1.PO, T1.POTNM,
                           I.CargaTotalIN, I.DescargaTotalIN, I.DescargaDSIGIN, 
                           E.CargaTotal, E.CargaTotalVuelo, E.DescargaTotal, E.DescargaDSIG, 
                           S.FCGrabadas, S.FCGrabVuelos,
                           T2.FCConformadas
            FROM Meses M
            INNER JOIN tecnica1 T1 ON T1.Mes = M.Mes
            INNER JOIN inspeccion I ON I.Mes = M.Mes 
            INNER JOIN empadronamiento E ON E.Mes = M.Mes
            INNER JOIN SistemaInfGeografica S ON S.Mes = M.Mes
            INNER JOIN tecnica2 T2 ON T2.Mes = M.Mes
            ';

    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (!$query) {
        die ('SQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
    }

                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
                        {
                            echo    '<tr>
                        <td class="tg-r8b1" style="text-align:center;">'.$row['Mes'].'</td>
                        <td  style="text-align:center;">'.$row['M'].'</td>
                        <td  style="text-align:center;">'.$row['MH'].'</td>
                        <td  style="text-align:center;">'.$row['DJ'].'</td>
                        <td  style="text-align:center;">'.$row['R'].'</td>
                        <td  style="text-align:center;">'.$row['PO'].'</td>
                        <td  style="text-align:center;">'.$row['POTNM'].'</td>
                        <td  style="text-align:center;">'.$row['CargaTotalIN'].'</td>
                        <td  style="text-align:center;">'.$row['DescargaTotalIN'].'</td>
                        <td  style="text-align:center;">'.$row['DescargaDSIGIN'].'</td>
                        <td  style="text-align:center;">'.$row['CargaTotal'].'</td>
                        <td  style="text-align:center;">'.$row['CargaTotalVuelo'].'</td>
                        <td  style="text-align:center;">'.$row['DescargaTotal'].'</td>
                        <td  style="text-align:center;">'.$row['DescargaDSIG'].'</td>
                        <td  style="text-align:center;">'.$row['FCGrabadas'].'</td>
                        <td  style="text-align:center;">'.$row['FCGrabVuelos'].'</td>
                        <td  style="text-align:center;">'.$row['FCConformadas'].'</td>

                        ';}
```